# login page with background animation

Tags: android, animation, authentication

please check out this link [TataWorld](http://tataworld.com/) , 
I want to create a login page with some animation in the background like that , 
basically a noob, so please explain how i can achieve that on gingerbread.

Answer (score 0):

check this link its give you idea to how create a login page.

http://techblogon.com/android-login-registration-screen-with-sqlite-database-example/

For animated backgroud.

http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2010/02/01/live-wallpapers-with-android-sdk-2-1.html

Comment: thanks for the help with login page designing but i also need that animation background

Comment: is that link helps you?

Comment: live wallpaper cannot be used on the app, but it runs behind on the OS right.

Comment: @manohar3787 use gif or short videos as background